# Modify WooCommerce orders page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to modify my WooCommerce orders page but I don't have the experience for this. At the moment (like in normal case) my orders page looks like this:

[image]

Yesterday I've added a second id attribute to each order where I can set a custom customer id (user_id in Wordpress). This field is named "second_customer".

I'm doing this because I want to show the order taken by customer one to an other customer too in case the "second_customer" has his user_id as value.

Now I need to modify the orders.php and modify it so that the orders gets loaded to for the "second_customer" on his account and the normal way too. So my question is: How can I get exacly the row like in the picture (the order) for the user id defined in my custom attribute?

Answer (score 1):

As your question:
How can I get exacly the row like in the picture 
use the table HTML elements like will result like the screen shoot above with  5 headings rows with table headings-  and table rows- :

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Product Id</th>
    <th>Date</th> 
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#356</td>
    <td>30 September</td>
    <td>Customer</td>
    <td>10 Address st, China</td>
    <td>John Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>#357</td>
    <td>30 September</td>
    <td>Customer</td>
    <td>32 Address st, Porland</td>
    <td>Sarah smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>#358</td>
    <td>29 September</td>
    <td>Customer</td>
    <td>55 Address st, New York</td>
    <td>Ben Barber</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```